# UIBarButtonItem to go back is not showing up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have no idea why the back button is not being shown after i press a cell on a table. Now i read that on the parent controller (where you click on the cell to move on to the next view) that you should insert this code:

```
   UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:nil
                                    action:nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:newBackButton];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = navBarItems;
```

And this is how the setup is done:

[image]

So my question is why is the back button item not showing up when i click on a cell?

Note:

The funny thing is that i am using a UIPageView where the back button is showing where i use the same code as i did in the parent view controller. So what am i missing? AND i know for sure that is was working on the previous IOS versions. This happened after upgrading maybe that will help you guys a bit?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The back button is not being shown because, in the current `UINavigationController`there is only the cell detail screen so it has nothing to go back to.

I think that you should put that `UINavigationController` in front of the `UIViewController` that holds your `UITableView`

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by that, but the two table views to the left in the image have both a UINavigationController if thats what you mean?

Comment: Try removing the `UINavigationController` in between the tableviews and the detailview

Comment: Now with some tweaking it did work, however some other stuff is not working because of that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UIButton *aBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,50, 64)];
    [aBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]];
    aBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    aBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    aBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    [aBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:65/255.0 blue:96/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [aBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *aBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:aBtn];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = aBarBtn;

-(void)popViewController
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did not work, Also no image is needed. I simply just want a back arrow meaning no title name or no image.

Comment: If you want back button without any titles means just add parentview controller navigationitem backbutton as " " empty text in storyboard.I hope there is no other action needed except poptoviewcontroller or try this [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" "
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:nil